# long (or bizarre) file paths

Tags: files, posix, path

I know that (on Linux at least, with native file systems like Ext3) file paths can in theory be quite long, and `PATH_MAX` is *often* (but not always) as big as 4096 (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9449307/841108); and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/833308/841108) explains it could be longer or runtime defined!).

However, file paths are often constructed on the fly, and it not uncommon in C to code something like

```
#define MY_PATH_MAX 256
char pathbuf[MY_PATH_MAX];
snprintf (pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf), "%s/%s", getenv("HOME"), somevar);
FILE *f = fopen(pathbuf, "r");
//// etc, avoiding error checks for simplicity
```

Now, I believe that having `MY_PATH_MAX`  being not too big (in particular to avoid consuming a lot of space on the call stack frame) is *practically* important and sensible. So, in the above example doing `#define MY_PATH_MAX PATH_MAX` would be silly (no need to spend 4Kbytes in my call frame).

I'm coding since 1974 and I never met a case where a file path was larger than a screen width, e.g. 80 characters or so. All the file systems I heard about did not have very deep directory hierarchy (a file with 8 directories above it is very unusual).

So, is my intuition correct? Does real software care about such long or bizarre file paths? Likewise, I never met any file name containing a newline (and I strongly recommend against spaces in file names!).

<sup>IIUC, you won't be able to build a GNU software like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) in a directory whose name contain spaces or newlines... very likely `autoconf` related scripts would suffer.... Also, there is simply no way to give in your `/etc/passwd`  a `$HOME` containing newline or even a colon `:` -since [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) does not support it.</sup>

Is my practical limit of 256 bytes in a file path a good limit?

<sup>Per the comments, I just upgraded it to 384...</sup>

Do you have a practical example where long file path names are relevant? I'm mostly interested in POSIX or Linux systems!

Comment: Most windows APIs have a 260 char limit and it's annoying as hell.

Comment: Really? Why? Could you give a real life example in some answer? And would 1024 or 4086 also be annoying?

Comment: Mostly hits my media collections. If you include artist, album and song name you can get names that are pretty long. Add a few directories on top of that and you can easily hit 260. I don't think I've hit 512 yet.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: that might be a good answer.... Are you suggesting a 512 char limits, or to always use PATH_MAX ?

Comment: [This](http://blog.codinghorror.com/filesystem-paths-how-long-is-too-long/) is somewhat related and quite amusing.

Comment: ...273 characters: the longest path on a semi-clean install of Windows 8.1.

Comment: In an ideal world we'd operate strictly on arbitrary-length strings, and either have a single PATH_MAX sanity check at the end or rely on the underlying file system API to return an appropriate error code, so we'd never have to worry about guessing the max ourselves. Too bad C doesn't provide any easy way of doing that...

Comment: One example that I've seen of excessively long paths are Scala (generated) classfile names. There are many Scala projects (including the compiler itself) that you can't build on *eCryptfs* (the default home-directory encryption on Linux), which has a 240 character pathname limit.

Comment: And as a general comment: why not just store on the heap. Perhaps as a linked-list structure where each node holds an arbitrary-length path component? Yeah, it's overkill for tiny pathnames, but I suspect that it won't be called so often that the overhead is noticeable.

Comment: I have definitely had paths that exceeded 256 characters. With the name of a path component limited to 255 characters, even folder/file can easily be 500 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does real software care about such long or bizarre file paths?

There is no such thing as a long or bizarre file path.  There are only valid and invalid file paths, and real software -- *correct* software -- sees the valid ones as strings of bytes and doesn't care about the contents.

> Is my practical limit of 256 bytes in a file path a good limit?

Absolutely not.  Nor is your revised limit of 384.

The practical limit on any system that defines `PATH_MAX` is `PATH_MAX` whether the actual value behind it is 5, 50, 500 or 5,000.  (256 is the *minimum* required by POSIX.)

`PATH_MAX` is the system's way of telling you exactly how many characters to expect in a valid path.  Using buffers that are any smaller limits your program to being able to handle a subset of the valid paths on the system.  That will serve to aggravate users of your program that run afoul of this limitation and makes more work for you when they ask that you adhere to the established standard.

Unless you can describe a specific, actual problem that is solved by using truncated buffers, there's no reason to be using anything other than `PATH_MAX`.  The 1970s were over 35 years ago, and `PATH_MAX` bytes for a path on most stacks isn't an issue.  If you're in a stack-constrained environment, odds are good you're probably not going to be opening a lot of files, and if you are, that environment's `PATH_MAX` will be something small enough to accommodate it.

Comment: In theory you are right. In practice, few people have a newline in their `$HOME`, and more significantly, most scripts would fail, or behave wrongly, if you did. It is not a black & white situation.... BTW, `/etc/passwd` does not even allow you to enter a `$HOME`  with a newline.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:  That doesn't change the fact that a path with a newline is, as far as the kernel is concerned, valid.  The fact that scripts trip over it in the password file is a problem that exists entirely in userland.

Comment: Agreed, but I was not talking about a kernel module.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:  Whatever ultimately operates on files (kernel or what have you) is what determines the valid length/content of paths.  The fact that the password file's format limits home directories to not having newlines is really only germane to things that have to deal with that file.  Not coding to handle valid is like having one of those "this should never happen" comments in your source and having it happen.  Because eventually, it will.

Answer (score 6):

I am very opposed to building unnecessary restrictions into our software, unless we really are in a very resource-constrained environment (e.g. embedded systems). Whenever we think that “nobody is ever going to need that”, somebody will certainly run into these arbitrary restrictions.

A maximum path length is fundamentally at odds with the hierarchical, tree-oriented, recursive model of modern file systems. A path addresses a node in this tree, and there should be no fundamental difference in addressing between a tree and its subtree. Yet imposing a length limit on the overall path means that in extreme cases we can address a file from a subdirectory that can't be addressed from a parent directory. E.g. if our path lengths were limited to ten bytes, to address the file `/a/b/c/d.txt` (12 bytes + terminator), we could `chdir` into `/a/b` and then address the file as `c/d.txt`. Having to `chdir` just to open a file really sucks.

In practice, long path names can occur due to a variety of reasons:

- File systems are a database. Some programs use hashes as key in this database, e.g. Git or Firefox. while both are very tame as they only use fairly short paths such as `./.git/objects/07/5f3cb2c7deb3abb3ce6b7e6eb8b83ff34c883c` (relative path, 56 bytes + terminator) or `~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/********.default/cache2/entries/1101BEDA093DDE5562CCC4FE6CF1C4538D36022E` (relative path, 97 bytes + terminator), there is no reason why someone shouldn't have multiple hashes in a path.
- Many programming toolchains use long paths. For example, Java has a convention where a package name such as `com.example.product.awesome.backend.dataaccesslayer.util` can lead to a path `./src/com/example/product/awesometool/backend/dataaccesslayer/util/SecondaryProductInformationVisitorManagerFactory.java` (facetious example, relative path, 120 bytes + terminator). I ran a query on my file system to find the longest path, and it turned up a file in a NodeJS package called `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-js/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/insert-module-globals/node_modules/combine-source-map/node_modules/inline-source-map/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/indexed-source-map-consumer.js` (real example, no symlinks, 298 bytes + terminator). Though I have to admit, that appears to be a horrible project layout.
- Symlinks are fun. Especially when they are at the end of a long path and point to a directory. Of course, symlinks have real uses, e.g. for configuration management.

I'd strongly suggest to get away from a fixed-size mindset. Scale as needed, since one size doesn't fit all. If you don't want to allocate a 4KB buffer on the stack, then don't. Your example in the question is particularly bad because you can easily find out how much space you need, and simply `malloc` that much – or use variable length arrays, if your compiler allows. If it turns out that someone has passed you megabytes of data, you can explicitly fail with that reason, but trying to access a half-copied filename is even worse. I think Steele and Sussman have put it better than me in their 1979 “*Design of LISP-Based Processors or, SCHEME: a Dielectric LISP or, Finite Memories Considered Harmful or, LAMBDA: The Ultimate Opcode*” memo:

> As far as the LISP programmer is concerned, new data objects are available in endless supply. They can be conveniently called forth to serve some immediate purpose and discarded when they are no longer in use. […]
>
> The immense freedom this gives the programmer may be seen by an example taken from current experience. A sort of error message familiar to most programmers is “too many nested DO loops”, or “more than 200 declared arrays” or “symbol table overflow”. Such messages typically arise within compilers or assemblers which were written in languages requiring data tables to be pre-allocated [at compile time] to some fixed length. The author of a compiler, for example, might well guess, “No one will even use more than, say, ten nested DO loops; I'll double that for good measure, and make the nested-DO-loop-table 20 long.” Inevitably, someone eventually finds some reason to write 21 nested DO loops, and finds the compiler overflows its fixed table and issues an error message (or worse yet, *doesn't* issue an error message). On the other hand, had the compiler writer made the table 100 long or 1000 long, most of the time most of the memory space devoted to that table would be wasted.

Of course, they are talking about early Fortran and its aversion to dynamic memory management. The irony here is that C absolutely does support dynamic memory allocation, although it is admittedly cumbersome. If you need some help to keep track of all that memory, you can always use C++…

Comment: You might also mention that the GNU extension function `asprintf()` does exactly what is needed in this case: it allocates a buffer to fit the created string. No need to calculate the expected size of the string yourself (which would be a likely source of errors).

Answer (score 5):

**Don't make users hate you: allow whatever the underlying system is likely to allow.**

I recall running into file path problems in a reasonably large business in which assets (of several types, for products which contained content subdivided components) were stored in a folder structure that went something like:

- Department name
- Team name
- Product family name
- Product name
- Release name
- Component
- Sub-component
- Asset type

That's eight levels not including an identifier for the network drive and filename. Virtually none of these would be close to eight characters. Release name might include a date; product names would often be be of the order of "Inspirational Product Title Mark 3 Client Manual (Swiss German)".

And that's optimistic: very often another level or two of hierarchy would creep in.